# Change Display Resolution from Windows Service (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, api, service, system

( Hi, everyone.  I'm very new to Windows programming, so I apologize in advance if this has already been asked and I just didn't know what to search for, but this problem has been driving me crazy and I know someone could probably answer this really easily. )

My company has an application that runs as a service in Windows 7.  I have been tasked with writing code to change display settings, but I apparently cannot do this from a system service.  I created a small executable that changes the color depth to 8bpp in about 5-10 lines of code, but when I place this code in my application, it returns success yet does not actually succeed (nothing changes).

Without a commanding knowledge of how Windows programming works, I have managed to try a MILLION different things to get it to work but with no avail.  Can somebody PLEASE help me find what I need to do to make this code function?

Comment: You can't. Services run under a different desktop than the user in Vista and above, and therefore have no access to the user's desktop.

Comment: I found a post somewhere, though, that said that this was possible.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249677

I actually tried this, but SetThreadDesktop failed with error code 0.  Also, I have been told that the Spice Desktop Agent accomplishes this, so it MUST be possible!

Comment: That KB article dates from the days when services ran in the same session as interactive desktops, i.e. XP time. Those days are long gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Vista and upwards services run in a different session ([session 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx)) and are isolated from the interactive desktop(s). This means that code that you run from the service is simply unable to make the changes you want. The obvious conclusion is that you need to run code in the interactive desktop.

Now you can do this, but it's not exactly easy to achieve. What you will need to do is arrange for your service to launch an process that runs on the interactive desktop: [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx). That process, rather than the service, is what will have to make the changes.

Whilst it is possible to achieve what you want, I think you should regard the difficulties involved as a signal to review whether or not your proposed approach is the best solution to whatever your underlying problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the response, David.  My company's demands are that we can set the resolution from a system service... that's it.  No room for reevaluation.  Is there any sort of COM call or command line call or ANYTHING that you can think of that might be able to accomplish this?

Comment: No, just what I said in the answer. The changes have to be made in code run from the interactive desktop. In order for this to work you are going to want your service to run under the Local System account. Otherwise starting a process on the interactive desktop involves terrible hacks. Your company's demands may be unrealistic. You could be in for some fun!  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, unrealistic demands are kind of a staple of my company.  I came across something posted somewhere that we can execute ChangeDisplaySettingsEx from the command line somehow... ?  A call to rundll32 shell32.dll I believe?  Any info about that?

Comment: @DanielS If your service does that then it will run in the context of the desktop attached to the service. In session 0. This is the desktop that you can't see. No matter what questions you ask me I will simply reiterate the answer. You need to run the code attached to the interactive desktop.

Comment: @DanielS - The answer has been NO 5 times now. ;) Would it help if I said it again as well? You can't do this with Windows Vista and later, no matter how many times you don't want to hear the answer. :) +1, David - I got caught up in something after making my comment to the original question, and couldn't come back in time to post an answer before you did. <g>

Comment: @David, in similar scenario, how about calling some functions in Dxva2.dll. Say GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR , is that possible? The code that runs from a console app returns false when part of service. Just want to ensure what I am experiancing is Session 0 isolation or something different. My env is Windows 10 btw.